# Typically, do same-sized SMD ceramic capacitors with different capacitance have different ESR?

Tags: esr

I know that depending on the dielectric, the technology, the company etc, but typically, if say two SMD ceramic capacitors are the exact same size (also of the same technology if you wish,) and their only difference is their capacitance, which one of them has the highest ESR?

Do they "typically" have the same ESR, since ESR it is mainly dependent on the size of the capacitor?

Note that this question goes for impedance as well. Will those two caps have typically the same impedance?

**EDIT:** Example:

These two capacitors are all the same but their capacitance. One is 1000pF (0.001uF) and the other 0.1uF.

They [share the same datasheet](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/40/X7RDielectric-777024.pdf) which does not state if capacitance affects ESR, for the same size capacitor.

[image]

Comment: Ceramics? Or other smd types ?

Comment: Ceramics. Let me edit this

Comment: slightly confused: capacitors from the same technology with different capacities but identical voltage rating typically have different volume. So, if two capacitors are comparable, but don't have the same capacity, they won't have the same volume. Or are you interpreting "size" differently?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well 10nF and 100nF in 0805 look like they have about the same thickness/volume, probably because if they made the lower value too thin it would crack...

Comment: I am adding an example on my question.

Comment: Two ways to get it : work it out from the dissipation factor, and look at the bottom of the V-shaped impedance/frequency curve. Both suggest no, ESR will increase as value reduces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Murata has a very nice website "[simsurfing](https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/mlcc.html?lcid=en-us)" which can display all sorts of measurements for their components, like ESR, ESL, S-parameters, Z, etc.

These are X7R MLCCs in 0603 size, values are 10nF 100nF 1µF 10µF, from various series.

[image]

Inductance is pretty similar, it mostly depends on package size.

ESR is lower for higher value caps (probably due to having more plates in parallel). It also depends on which capacitor series you get.

You can also compare 1nF 0603 C0G (blue) and X5R/X7R ; C0G has much lower ESR.

[image]

Note X7R/X5R are only useful for decoupling, and their ESR is usually "low enough" that you don't need to check. In fact, it is usually too low, and that causes bad damping and resonance peaks in power supply impedance, ringing with ferrite beads, etc.

Murata makes "controlled ESR" ceramic caps which have more civilized (ie, higher) ESR for better damping, but the price is ridiculous.

If you're wondering about the ESR of ceramic caps because you're looking at a LDO datasheet that wants a special snowflake tantalum capacitor with just the right amount of ESR that costs 10x the price of the LDO, then get a LDO that specs "stable with ceramic caps".

If you're interested in how much ripple current the ceramic caps around a switching converter can take, that's usually mentioned in the datasheet too (and for µF MLCCs it is surprisingly high).

For C0G, if you use it in a filter then ESR becomes part of the resistive impedance, and depending on frequency it can matter quite a lot. So it is important to check.

Comment: "special snowflake tantalum" haha

Comment: a cheap electrolytic will work just as well as the expensive tantalum though, plus it doesn't burst into flames

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the same capacitor series, and the ESR is listed in the datasheet for that series, then yes, one can assume that different capacitances of that series will have the ESR listed in the datasheet.
If not the ESR will vary between manufacturers, capacitance, probably even based on the specific factory making the ceramics for a specific batch.

Note how ESR is often not listed on many ceramic capacitor datasheets. The ESR of ceramic capacitors are very low. If it is "very low" or "very low" X 0,5 does that even matter? If the ESR is important to your circuit you need to be very specific on your BOM.